# how to add assembly info to PrecompiledViews dll generated by dot net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

views in my .net core 2.0 project is getting generated in PrecompiledViews dll.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x

How to add the assembly info to this dll, information such as company name, copyrights etc.

Comment: figured out how to do this?

Comment: no, i didn't  get the solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to modified project file. like below. Able to see version information on DLL.
Hope this will help you.

**Note** : Just publish on local, did not test the publish on server.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Assembly">
  <AssemblyName>HegicMvc_Poc.PrecompiledViews</AssemblyName>
  <PackageId>Library</PackageId>
  <Product>Library</Product>
  <Authors>StackOverflow Answer</Authors>
  <Company>Test</Company>
  <Description>Library</Description>
  <Copyright>Copyright © 2016 - 2017 Test</Copyright>
  <Version>2.0.0</Version>
  <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
  <FileVersion>1.0.0</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Before publish**
 [image: Before publish]

**After publish**

[image: After publish]

Comment: this did not work, just changed the name of the main exe to the assembly name, and created a ".PreCompiledViews.dll" still without the information

Comment: is Project name append with your "PreCompiledViews.dll"? like mine

Comment: yes, I added the project name + precompiled, it compiled my princial executable with precombiled.dll in name, and created another precompiled.precompiled.dll

Comment: Did you try to delete another one and check?

Comment: is it possible to give those version from a .cs file, i need to version this during build time.

Comment: I think not because this DLL not generating during build time. if is generating during build time then may be possible.